# Wordpress site not loading wordpress folders

Tags: wordpress

I developed a wordpress site on my localhost and then hosted it later but after completing it, the site was just appearing without been styled. I had to debug from developer tools and noticed the entire wordpress folder is not been loaded. i have cross check the file path from my cpanel and every thing is intact but still not working. Only the index file is been loaded with an error message of: 
failed to load resource::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does the error message tell you what resource failed to load? If it is code from a plugin or theme try deactivating that particular resource and see if everything else works.